# I can't get TestDriven.NET to show up in my installation of Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testdriven.net

I've used TestDriven.NET in the past (with Visual Studio 2005), but now that I've got a new installation of Visual Studio 2010 on a different computer, I can't see either the Add-In Manager, or the TestDriven.NET stuff, even though I have them installed.

Help, please!  It's making me bonkers.

Note: trying with current version (3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to the fact that I was using one of the free versions of Visual Studio, which did not allow for Add-ins.